# Is there a problem with building an AR(1) model with a not-necessarily-stationary/ergodic time series if our goal is prediction?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, stationarity, ergodic, probabilistic-forecasts

Let's say that we have a real-valued observed time series of length $T$:
$$\\{ (t_i, x_{t_i}) : i \in \\{0, \dots, T-1\\} \\}, x_{t_i} \in \mathbb{R}.$$

We would ultimately like to probabilistically predict future values of the time series from lagged values of the time series.

Is the following a valid methodology to do that from a statistical standpoint?

First, suppose a model:

$$x_{t_i}= f(x_{t_{i-1}}) + \epsilon_{t_i}$$

Second, Estimate the functional form of $f$ via plotting $x_{t_i}$ against $x_{t_{i-1}}$.

Third, using this functional form, calculate the errors and analyze the dependence structure between the lags and if negligible enough, derive some distributional form for the errors such as by fitting a distribution to them, else repeat the previous modeling process on the errors/lagged errors.

This would then give us a probabilistic prediction model that we could then evaluate through cross-validation which I think would circumvent some of the problems associated with not assuming stationarity/ergodicity of our DGP such as the relationship not holding out of sample.